# How can i convert String to Dictionary to access nested array and dictionary, i want to access stateId and stateName to add in to my table

Tags: iphone, swift

i

```
func callAddWithPOST(Name mname:String, PhoneNo mphone:String, Email memail:String, Comment mcomments:String){
    let login = ["countryId":"1"]
    print("Your Result is : = \(login)")
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://photokeeper.mgtcloud.co.uk/commonwebservice.asmx/getStateList")!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    do {
        let auth = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(login, options: .PrettyPrinted)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = auth
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let result = self.convertStringToDictionary(responseString!)
            let keys = Array(result!.values)
            print(keys[0])
            print("Done.")
        })
        task.resume()
    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

**output**

```
{"result":[{"stateId":3871,"stateName":"Aberdeenshire"},{"stateId":3872,"stateName":"Anglesey/Sir Fon"},{"stateId":3873,"stateName":"Angus"},{"stateId":3874,"stateName":"Antrim"},{"stateId":3875,"stateName":"Argyll And Bute"},{"stateId":3876,"stateName":"Armagh"},{"stateId":3877,"stateName":"Ayrshire"},{"stateId":3878,"stateName":"Bedfordshire"},{"stateId":3879,"stateName":"Berkshire"},{"stateId":3880,"stateName":"Blaenau Gwent/Blaenau Gwent"},{"stateId":3881,"stateName":"Bristol"},{"stateId":3882,"stateName":"Buckinghamshire"},{"stateId":3883,"stateName":"Caerphilly/Caerffili"},{"stateId":3884,"stateName":"Cambridgeshire"},{"stateId":3885,"stateName":"Cardiff/Caerdydd"},{"stateId":3886,"stateName":"Cardiganshire/Ceredigion"},{"stateId":3888,"stateName":"Carmarthenshire/Sir Gaerfyrddin"},{"stateId":3890,"stateName":"Cheshire"},{"stateId":3891,"stateName":"Clackmannanshire"},{"stateId":3893,"stateName":"Conwy/Conwy"},{"stateId":3895,"stateName":"County Durham"},{"stateId":3896,"stateName":"Cumbria"},{"stateId":3897,"stateName":"Denbighshire/Sir Ddinbych"},{"stateId":3898,"stateName":"Derbyshire"},{"stateId":3899,"stateName":"Devon"},{"stateId":3901,"stateName":"Dorset"},{"stateId":3902,"stateName":"Down"},{"stateId":3904,"stateName":"Dumfries And Galloway"},{"stateId":3905,"stateName":"Dunbartonshire"},{"stateId":3906,"stateName":"Dundee"},{"stateId":3907,"stateName":"Durham/North Yorkshire"},{"stateId":3908,"stateName":"East Lothian"},{"stateId":3909,"stateName":"East Sussex"},{"stateId":3910,"stateName":"East Yorkshire"},{"stateId":3911,"stateName":"Edinburgh"},{"stateId":3912,"stateName":"Essex"},{"stateId":3913,"stateName":"Fermanagh"},{"stateId":3914,"stateName":"Fife"},{"stateId":3915,"stateName":"Flintshire/Sir Fflint"},{"stateId":3917,"stateName":"Glamorgan/Morgannwg"},{"stateId":3918,"stateName":"Glasgow"},{"stateId":3919,"stateName":"Gloucestershire"},{"stateId":3920,"stateName":"Gwynedd/Gwynedd"},{"stateId":3921,"stateName":"Hampshire"},{"stateId":3922,"stateName":"Herefordshire"},{"stateId":3923,"stateName":"Hertfordshire"},{"stateId":3924,"stateName":"Highland"},{"stateId":3925,"stateName":"Kent"},{"stateId":3929,"stateName":"Lanarkshire"},{"stateId":3930,"stateName":"Lancashire"},{"stateId":3932,"stateName":"Leicestershire"},{"stateId":3935,"stateName":"Lincolnshire"},{"stateId":3936,"stateName":"London"},{"stateId":3937,"stateName":"Londonderry"},{"stateId":3940,"stateName":"Manchester"},{"stateId":3943,"stateName":"Merthyr Tydfil/Merthyr Tydfil"},{"stateId":3944,"stateName":"Midlothian"},{"stateId":3946,"stateName":"Monmouthshire/Sir Fynwy"},{"stateId":3947,"stateName":"Moray"},{"stateId":3948,"stateName":"Neath Port Talbot"},{"stateId":3949,"stateName":"Newport"},{"stateId":3950,"stateName":"Norfolk"},{"stateId":3951,"stateName":"Northamptonshire"},{"stateId":3952,"stateName":"Northumberland"},{"stateId":3953,"stateName":"Nottinghamshire"},{"stateId":3955,"stateName":"Orkney"},{"stateId":3956,"stateName":"Oxfordshire"},{"stateId":3957,"stateName":"Pembrokeshire/Sir Benfro"},{"stateId":3958,"stateName":"Perth And Kinross"},{"stateId":3959,"stateName":"Powys/Powys"},{"stateId":3960,"stateName":"Renfrewshire"},{"stateId":3962,"stateName":"Rutland"},{"stateId":3963,"stateName":"Scottish Borders"},{"stateId":3964,"stateName":"Shetland Isles"},{"stateId":3965,"stateName":"Shropshire"},{"stateId":3967,"stateName":"Somerset"},{"stateId":3968,"stateName":"South Yorkshire"},{"stateId":3969,"stateName":"Staffordshire"},{"stateId":3970,"stateName":"Stirling"},{"stateId":3971,"stateName":"Suffolk"},{"stateId":3972,"stateName":"Surrey"},{"stateId":3973,"stateName":"Swansea"},{"stateId":3975,"stateName":"Torfaen"},{"stateId":3976,"stateName":"Tyrone"},{"stateId":3977,"stateName":"Warwickshire"},{"stateId":3979,"stateName":"West Lothian"},{"stateId":3980,"stateName":"West Midlands"},{"stateId":3981,"stateName":"West Sussex"},{"stateId":3982,"stateName":"West Yorkshire"},{"stateId":3983,"stateName":"Western Isles"},{"stateId":3987,"stateName":"Wiltshire"},{"stateId":3988,"stateName":"Worcestershire"},{"stateId":3989,"stateName":"Wrexham"}],"status":"success"}
```

Done.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting `data` to `String` try to convert it `Dictionary` direct

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    let response = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.MutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
    let status = response["status"] as! String
    if status == "success" {
        let array = response["result"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
        print(array)
    }
})
```

**Note:** You have already written your code inside do block thats why i have not declare that block for try, you just need to replace your task block with my one.

**Edit:**

```
func callAddWithPOST(Name mname:String, PhoneNo mphone:String, Email memail:String, Comment mcomments:String){
    let login = ["countryId":"1"]
    print("Your Result is : = \(login)")
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://photokeeper.mgtcloud.co.uk/commonwebservice.asmx/getStateList")!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    do {
        let auth = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(login, options: .PrettyPrinted)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = auth
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            let response = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.MutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject]
            let status = response["status"] as! String
            if status == "success" {
                let array = response["result"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
                print(array)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error on using your task block ->    "   
Invalid conversion from throwing function of type ‘(_,_,_) throws -> Void to non-throwing function type ‘(NSData?,NsURLRespnse?,NSError?)-> Void’
    "

Comment: Are you getting error on this line `let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in` ??

Comment: yes i am getting error on the line that you have mentioned.

Comment: Try to pass data with `!` in the `JSONObjectWithData`, check my latest edit for that.

Comment: yes i have done the same as you have instructed even i am getting the above error

Comment: no i was not getting the error before i have used that code. Can i show you the code i have modified to fix this issues.